# radar data for buoyancy measurements of cyclones

Tags: atmosphere, climate, climate-models, tropical-cyclone

I'm sorry if I'm asking in the wrong forum. I'm a computational scientist and I do not have much physics background.

I'm working on constructing machine learning models from data. Currently, I've only been working on toy problems using data generated from numerical simulations of physical processes. One example that has worked well for me is [this surface quasi-geostrophic model](https://pyqg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/sqg.html). The numerical simulation provides the buoyancy on a grid for various time steps. I'm training a machine learning model on this data to predict the buoyancy over a grid at a particular time for a different initial condition.

I'm now thinking whether this can be applied to a real data set. I've read that the surface quasi-geostrophic model is used to model cyclones. My question is: are there available data sets of the buoyancy of a cyclone over a spatial grid? I'd appreciate some references if there are any. Thanks!